# How do you Sum with conditional iterators in WL?

Tags: summation

Consider the following simple `Sum`:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, n1], {n1, 0, n, 1}, Assumptions -> n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> 2^n

This of course is not extendable to multiple groups, so we can try to do it using `Multinomial`:

```
Sum[
  Multinomial[n1, n2] * Boole[n1 + n2 == n],
  {n1, 0, n, 1}, {n2, 0, n, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> 2^n

which produces the correct result. But now I want to extend it to three indistinguishable groups:

```
Sum[
  Multinomial[n1, n2, n3] * Boole[n1 + n2 + n3 == n], 
  {n1, 0, n, 1}, {n2, 0, n, 1}, {n3, 0, n, 1},
  Assumptions -> n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

But this is not working (returns unevaluated). The expected result was:

> 3^n

How can I do a symbolic `Sum` with conditional iterators in the Wolfram language?

---

It seems Mathematica is not able to symbolic `Sum` with 3 or more iterators. So for example, if I replace `Multinomial[n1, n2, n3] * Boole[n1 + n2 + n3 == n]` by `Multinomial[n1, n2, n-n1-n2]` by manually doing the substitution then the following produces the correct result:

```
Sum[Multinomial[n1,n2,n-n1-n2],{n1,0,n,1},{n2,0,n,1}]//FullSimplify[FunctionExpand@#,Assumptions->n\[Element]PositiveIntegers]&
```

Now there is no way to avoid the three iterators for the case of four indistinguishable groups:

```
Sum[Multinomial[n1,n2,n3,n-n1-n2-n3],{n1,0,n,1},{n2,0,n,1},{n3,0,n,1}]
```

I wish there was a symbolic way to check this.

Comment: What is the expected result of the second calculation? "But this is not working" - exactly *how* is it not working? Does it return the wrong result? No result? Does it keep evaluating forever? It would seem to me that, if you got the first one to work, then conceptually your approach works. Only, MMA might not have any rules / hints built in to deal with the second summation.